# Angular 7 : Pagination not working properly

Tags: angular, typescript, ngx-pagination

I've problem with pagination. Sorry, I not so understand it how to make it working as expected by passing `this.total = res.totalPage;`from **Component** to **Service** to make it count page.Because it now just display 1 page only "[image reference](https://i.stack.imgur.com/OugKX.jpg)". Bellow I provide **html**, **Component** and **Service** code to make you easy to understand. 
In html code, I just show part pagination.

**HTML**

```
    <table
      mat-table
      [dataSource]="dataSource"
      matSort
      multiTemplateDataRows
      class="mat-elevation-z8-"
    >
    <ng-container
        matColumnDef="{{ column }}"
        *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay | paginate: { id: 'server', itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: total }"
      ><!-- -->
      <ng-container *ngIf="column === 'select'; else notSelect">
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef>
          <mat-checkbox (change)="$event ? masterToggle() : null"
                        [checked]="selection.hasValue() && isAllSelected()"
                        [indeterminate]="selection.hasValue() && !isAllSelected()">
          </mat-checkbox>
        </th>
        <td mat-cell *matCellDef="let row">
          <mat-checkbox (click)="$event.stopPropagation()"
                        (change)="$event ? selection.toggle(row) : null"
                        [checked]="selection.isSelected(row)"
                        >
          </mat-checkbox>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <ng-container *ngIf="column.length == 11"  matColumnDef="name"><!---->
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef mat-sort-header><strong>{{ column }}</strong></th>
      </ng-container>
      <ng-container #headerSort><!---->
        <th mat-header-cell *matHeaderCellDef><strong>{{ column }}</strong></th>
      </ng-container>
        <td
          mat-cell
          *matCellDef="let element"
          (click)="open(element)"
          class="pointer"
        >
        <p>
         {{element.name}}
         </p>
         <p *ngIf="column.length == 7">
            {{element.location}}
          </p>
          <p *ngIf="column.length == 6">
              {{element.status}}
          </p>
          <p *ngIf="column.length == 8">
            {{date}}
        </p>
        </td>
      </ng-container>

      <tr mat-header-row *matHeaderRowDef="columnsToDisplay"></tr>
      <tr
        mat-row
        *matRowDef="let element; columns: columnsToDisplay"
        class="example-element-row"
        [class.example-expanded-row]="expandedElement === element"

      ></tr>

      <tr
        mat-row
        *matRowDef="let item; columns: ['expandedDetail']"
        class="example-detail-row"
      ></tr>
    </table>
    <pagination-controls (pageChange)="loadAgents($event)" id="server"></pagination-controls>
```

**Component**

```
ngOnInit() {
    this.getPage(1);
}

getPage(page: number) {
  this.allService.getAllService(pageIndex).subscribe(res =>{
  this.dataSource = new MatTableDataSource<AllDetails>(res['allList']);

  this.total = res.totalPage;
  console.log(this.total)
  this.p = pageIndex;
  this.dataSource.sort = this.sort;

 }
}
```

**Service**

```
getAllService(page:number): Observable<any>  {
    console.log("TEST page back" +page)
    const urls: string = `http://192.168.0.101:9080/project/api/listall/${orgId}`
   const requestUrl: string = `${urls}/${page + 1}/desc`;

    return this.http.get<AllDetails>(requestUrl).pipe(map(res => {
      return {
        allList: res['allList'],
        noPage: res['noPage'],
        totalPage: res['totalPage']
      };
  }));

  }
```

Part `noPage: res['noPage']`  refer to current page.

I've [example](https://stackblitz.com/edit/ngx-pagination-server-side-xdzsnb) pagination code but I don't know to implement in my code.

Hope you all can help.

Thanks in advance

Comment: The link to your example does not seem to be correct.

Comment: Sorry my bad... I've edit it

Answer (score 0):

Try changing

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="{{ column }}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay | 
  paginate: { id: 'server', itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: total }">
```

to

```
<ng-container matColumnDef="{{ column }}" *ngFor="let column of columnsToDisplay | 
async | paginate: { id: 'server', itemsPerPage: 10, currentPage: p, totalItems: total }">
```

Comment: Thank for answer... But I got error `ERROR Error: "InvalidPipeArgument:`

Comment: Can you add the code where you are creating `columnsToDisplay` ?

Comment: `columnsToDisplay: string[]  = ['select','Name','Status', 'Location.' , 'Date'];`

Comment: Are you sure columnsToDisplay has length of more than 10 items. As you have limited `itemsPerPage` to 10 so for `pagination` to show more than one page `columnsToDisplay` must have more than 10 items.

Comment: Yes it has 9 page. 10 length per page. I `console.log(total)` it come out 9

Comment: Okay try making it more than 10 and also increase the length of `columnsToDisplay` more than 10 too

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/198293/discussion-between-swapy-and-azzam-asghar).